# Can't login into Ubuntu VM

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, login-screen

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 32 bits into VirtualBox on a Windows 8.1 32 bits, but when I try to login, it just sits there for a while thinking, a black screen pops and it goes back to the users, it goes the same for all users even guest, I have also tried making a new user using alt+F1 but it's all the same thing

Using Unity btw

Comment: Are you using Unity?

Comment: Yes, Its the unity interface

Comment: Try purging and reinstalling it from TTY. If you recently had other desktop environments installed, reinstall them, log into the last one you used, log out, log into Unity and then purge it.

Comment: @Zacharee1 sorry I should've stated I have very basic ubuntu knowledge, could you explain it better?

Comment: Did you install anything, like KDE or MATE?

Comment: Nope, just downloaded the ISO from the official website and could never login

Comment: And this happened right away?

Comment: Yeah, after installing everything, what I describe in the question happens all the time

Comment: Redownload the ISO